# Alter table with millions of rows with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run an alter command like below, except this table has 40 million rows, and the query takes forever.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsumerProduct]
ADD IsPendDefault [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
GO
```

Hence I thought of doing the alter with null, than updating every column for 40 million rows in batches of 5000 and than alter it back to not null.

Something like this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].ConsumerProduct
ADD IsPendDefault [bit] NULL
GO

SET ROWCOUNT 10000

WHILE (1=1) 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE ConsumerProduct 
    SET IsPendDefault = 0 
    WHERE IsPendDefault IS NULL

    -- Update 1000 nonupdated rows
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        BREAK
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END

ALTER TABLE [dbo].ConsumerProduct
ALTER COLUMN  IsPendDefault [bit] NOT NULL 
GO
```

Even this query takes forever. Is there any easier faster way to alter a table with a default value in the column.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I would use the primary key in the update where clause and update in batches.  I would make each batch a standalone statement and not rely on a loop.  Get Next 100,000 range kind of statement.

Answer (score 2):

In Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2012

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsumerProduct]
ADD IsPendDefault [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
```

is [an online operation](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/). So I assume you are not on EE.

Do you actually need to update all the column values to `0`?

One option would be to just allow the column to be nullable and default to `NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].ConsumerProduct
ADD IsPendDefault [bit] NULL
```

and make sure your code treats `NULL` as being `false`. e.g. with `SELECT ISNULL(IsPendDefault,0) AS IsPendDefault`.

If you do want to make it `NOT NULL` then breaking into batches and performing updates is the best solution. But you want to make sure that each update can quickly find its batch of rows to update without having to scan over rows already updated by previous batches.

So (if you have an integer identity primary key) an option would be to simply divide that up into ranges of your desired batch size and have each batch seek into its desired range.

```
DECLARE @I         INT = 0,
        @BatchSize INT = 5000;

WHILE @I <= (SELECT MAX(ID)
             FROM   ConsumerProduct)
  BEGIN
      UPDATE ConsumerProduct
      SET    IsPendDefault = 0
      WHERE  IsPendDefault IS NULL
             AND ID >= @I
             AND ID < @I + @BatchSize;

      SET @I = @I + @BatchSize;
  END
```

If you have large ranges that will be empty or extremely sparsely populated it might be worth a more elaborate approach.

```
CREATE TABLE #processed
  (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY
  )

DECLARE @ID        INT = 0,
        @BatchSize INT = 5000;

WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
      WITH T
           AS (SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) *
               FROM   ConsumerProduct
               WHERE  ID > @ID
                      AND IsPendDefault IS NULL
               ORDER  BY ID)
      UPDATE T
      SET    IsPendDefault = 0
      OUTPUT inserted.ID
      INTO #processed;

      IF @@ROWCOUNT < @BatchSize
        BREAK;

      SELECT @ID = MAX(ID)
      FROM   #processed;

      TRUNCATE TABLE #processed
  END

DROP TABLE #processed
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Unfortunately making it null is not an option because that will require code changes. Do you have a psedo code for the batching that you have in mind. I tried my own version of batching using rowcount but that performed worse than the solution I have up there

Comment: @prapoerfft - do you have an integer clustered primary key?

Comment: Yes there is an ID column Primary key in the table which is of type CLUSTERED

Comment: Thanks for the extensive solution. I am testing it out right now. I am also trying to understand since I am using SQL Server 2012, than why this operation is not online operation. It should only be a meta-data change and should be instantaneous. I didn't really understood your statement: 'is an online operation. So I assume you are not on EE.'

Comment: @prapoerfft - It's only a metadata only change on Enterprise Edition. Not standard edition or other editions.

Comment: I checked and I am using standard edition :(.                                         Product Version:          11.0.6020.0
Product Name:             SQL Server 2012
Product Level:            SP3 
Product Edition:          Standard Edition (64-bit)

Comment: I got this error when I tried running your solutions: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @prapoerfft there's nothing in my code that can cause that. Likely you have a buggy update trigger on the table.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits I don't need commit but have incorporated the other suggestion.